# Will Visual Studio 2003 and 2008 fail gracefully if I uninstall the MSDN library

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msdn, visual-studio-2003

I use google as my primary reference so I don't need a local copy of MSDN; and am trying to free up a few GB of disk space.

Before I pull the plug I'd like to make sure that my fatfingering the F1 key won't end up freezing visual studio up for even longer than it does with MSDN installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the f1 to go to the online msdn rather to the local one, and uninstall it.

Comment: Do you have any idea where in the options dialog I should be looking for that setting?

Comment: In VS2k8 the setting are under Tools-Options-Environment-Help-Online.

Comment: In VS2k3 Tools-Options-Environment-Help looks like where it should be set but none of the options I can change are pointing the help browser to http://msdn.microsoft.com/whatever urls instead of ms-help://whatever.

Comment: I'll need to find a computer with vs2k3 and check... this is a very old version (although the best msdn support was for VS 6).

Comment: True.  Unfortunately I still have one app built with it that uses a few 3rd party controls that don't work properly with the 2.0 or later frameworks.  I haven't actually done anything with it for while but don't want to break my tools either if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling MSDN is a supported action and should not cause any problems with your installation.